# Laravel 8 return all exceptions as json

Tags: php, json, laravel, exception

I´m trying to get all exceptions as jsons instead of the HTML that Laravel normally returns, but i cant get it to work in Laravel 8.

I found someone who did it in Laravel 5 with the following code in /app/Exceptions/handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return response(['error'=>$exception->getMessage()], $exception->getCode() ?: 400);
}
```

I found [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-render-function-in-handlerphp-not-working) thread where they explain how to get a custom exception to return as a json, but i cant get it to work for all exceptions.

I tried doing something like this:

```
public function register()
{
   $this->renderable(function (Exception $e, $request) {
    return response()->json('errors.custom', [], 500);
});
}
```

The exception that I'm testing it with is `Route [login] not defined.` but it still returns the HTML

Comment: why not use try catch blocks , `catch(Exception $e){return response(['error'=>$e->getMessage()], $e>getStatusCode());}`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Laravel by default will return the exception in JSON if the application header include: `Accept: application/json` which is reasonable because no app should send a content type that the requester cannot (or would not) accept to the requester. Are you sending a request that accepts JSON?

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for making me realize it was an XY problem, you're right, i included Accept: application/json as a header in the get request and it works flawlessly now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @apokryfos pointed out I was asking the wrong question, putting `Accept: application/json` as a header in the request is all you need to receive the response as a json

Answer (score 3):

Using `renderable` instead of `reportable` method in your exception `Handler.php` will help you return custom error message in any format you like https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#renderable-exceptions. Below is an example. In your `\App\Exceptions\Handler.php` register method, put the following code;

```
public function register()
    {
        // reportable
        $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
            return response(['error' => $e->getMessage()], $e->getCode() ?: 400);
        });
    }
```

On top of that you also need to change `Kernel.php` file to use the `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class` instead of the default `\App\Http\Middleware\Autheticate::class` to return the actually error and not  `Route [login] not defined` which happens when laravel tries to redirect unauthorized routes to login route. Here is the example;

```
> protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
>         'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class, // remove the \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
>         'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
>         'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
>         'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
>         'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
>         'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
>         'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
>         'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
>         'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
>     ];
```

Comment: I got status code 0 from $e->getCode(), is there anything that I missed?

Comment: @work sarah Usually error code 0 means there is no response or means the connection is very slow, or the response body is empty, which mostly the reason should be specific, or timeout in execution. Check which one is it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) {
    //业务逻辑
    //$code = $e->getStatusCode();
    //$msg = $e->getMessage();
});
```

[image]

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.html